# What does "もんじゃない" mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning, colloquial-language

I'm not too sure what it means. I've seen it used in a lot of different contexts, and the most I can gather is that it means something along the lines of, "it's not that". Is this correct, and if not, could someone explain it to me?

An example I saw in the lyrics of a song

> そんなかわいいもんじゃないけど 奪わないでいて

Answer (score 5, accepted):

もん is short for 物{もの}. That reading is shown under "Other forms" in [jisho.org](http://jisho.org/search/%E7%89%A9).

The most common meaning for もの is "(physical) thing," but もん is often used on the end of sentences to mean "reason" or "the (hypothetical) thing is," similar to (な)の.

> そんなかわいいもんじゃないけど
>   The thing is, it's not that cute, but...

もん often sounds somewhat childish, petulant, cutesy, or girly.

Here are some other [common uses of もん by Maggie-sensei](http://maggiesensei.com/2010/04/08/requested-lesson-%E3%80%8C%E3%82%82%E3%82%93%E3%81%8B%E3%80%8D%E3%80%8C%E3%82%82%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0%E3%80%8D%E3%80%8C%E3%81%A0%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A6%E3%80%8Dmonkamondadanante/)